# Messages show up only after refreshing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm building this chat app and when I type in a message, press enter, I can see in the console that the message is created and it also prints out this:

```
No template found for RoomMessagesController#create, rendering head :no_content Completed 204 No Content in 6760ms (ActiveRecord: 8.2ms)
```

and this is what I get in the browser:

[image]

And when I press refresh, the message shows up. What do I do?

[Here](https://github.com/Amir998/rails-chat-tutorial)'s the code.

Comment: Are you trying not to render view by adding head :no_content?

Comment: I added 'head :no_content' in attempt to fix the error.